# Auto yes to raid5 array script

Tags: bash, command, ubuntu-12.04, raid, mdadm

I am working on a script to install a array raid5. I am having trouble with inserting auto=yes when the script ask: if I want to continue creating array. I tried --auto=yes (http://www.linuxmanpages.com/man8/mdadm.8.php) but very unsure where to place it.

```
#!/bin/bash
mdadm mdadm --create --verbose /dev/md0 --level=5 --raid-devices=3 /dev/sdc1 /dev/sdd1 /dev/sde1 --spare-devices=1 /dev/sdf1

if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo OK
else
    echo FAIL
fi
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**1)**
you can use [HEREDOC](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html) to resolve such problems.

for example for `passwd` command:

```
#!/bin/bash
passwd user <<EOF
mypassword
mypassword
EOF
```

You can also run your script and put `heredoc` :

```
./script <<EOF
>yes
>yes
>no
>EOF
```

**UPDATE:**

**This is finally what you want**

if you have one question:

```
./script <<EOF
>yes
>EOF
```

Also you can:

```
#!/bin/bash
mdadm --create --verbose /dev/md0 --level=5 --raid-devices=3 /dev/sdc1 /dev/sdd1 /dev/sde1 --spare-devices=1 /dev/sdf1 <<EOF
yes
EOF
```

**2)**
There is also another solution:

```
yes | command-that-asks-for-input
```

or, if a capital 'Y' is required:

```
yes Y | command-that-asks-for-input
```

Comment: If i want to have it in a if as a script to check if the command ran or not. How will that work?

Comment: I didn't get you..what do you mean?

Comment: This is how my script looks, but still not working. Getting errors.


#!/bin/bash
mdadm mdadm --create --verbose /dev/md0 --level=5 --raid-devices=3 /dev/sdc1 /dev/sdd1 /dev/sde1 --spare-devices=1 /dev/sdf1 <<EOF
yes
EOF

if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo OK
else
    echo FAIL
fi

Comment: Here is the code: https://www.dropbox.com/s/5e5vjb9kbgjs4qw/kode.png  Using virtualbox so mdadm code is not fully showed.
Here is the error: https://www.dropbox.com/s/3la8kqhyob1h6fv/feilmelding.png

Comment: @user3185936 I assume you want to check the result of your action, yes?

Comment: Yes I checked it by cat /proc/mdstat. It showed up as md127. But when i deleted the array and did the script again I got this error:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/tykf1bx3j9vtgs3/kode2.png

Comment: Did and updated my script.
Are you sure to have two mdadm's? With One it runs but asks me if i want to continue creating array. How to put in auto=yes?
With two mdadm's I get errors.

Comment: I think with one mdadm should work...this solution or heredoc should work..else I dont know really :(

Comment: Thank you for helping! With one mdadm It runs I only needed auto=yes. Please help a pakistani brother.

Comment: ok...it asks a question right? what answer do you want to put?

Comment: just run `./script <<EOF yes EOF`

Comment: find `This is finally what you want` in answer part

Comment: That worked. But you have no idea how to put that in the script istead of the command line ?

./script <<EOF
>yes
>EOF

Comment: Thank you brother! Very good script working now! Salam from Pakistan.

Comment: @user3185936 you can upvote and accept the answer to help other guys

Comment: You found the answer and run away? :)]

Comment: I have accepted answar but cant upvote it because of low reputation.

Comment: good..no problem/// in such ways guys that have same questions can understand this question is answered